# How to download files from a FTP using PhantomJS

Tags: ftp, phantomjs, ftpwebrequest

I have a file on a FTP Server. I´m trying to download it using PhantomJS. I´ve tried using the following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.mywebsite.com/exempleFIle.xlsx');
phantom.exit();
```

It runs without throwing any errors, however the file is not downloaded. Is it possible to download it with PhantomJS?

My main goal is synchronizing the files in the FTP with my computer, so I can put it in my Google Drive and from there using it in my reports. I use PhantomJS to access some webpages and get some data for the same purpose. Since I´m already using PhantomJS, I thought I could do the same for the ftp server, but if there is a simpler solution that use other methods, I´m open to trying it.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is a headless web-browser, it's not an FTP client, so it won't be able to help you.

> My main goal is synchronizing the files in the FTP with my computer

I'd suggest using [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/).

`lftp -u user,password -e 'mirror /remote/server/files/ /local/computer/files/' ftp.myserver.com`

This will get files from the remote server to the local computer.